# IIS will not install on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5

I have a new PC running Windows 7 Professional 64 bit. I have an issue installing IIS - it goes through the install process, but at the end tells me "not all components could be installed", with no additional information given. There is no sign of an error in the install log or in event viewer.

However, at this point, IIS is installed and working! I can run IIS manager, browse to localhost and see the default page, but at the next reboot the system rolls back and th einstall vanishes.

I have tried installing II using the Windows Components section in Add/Remove Programs, I have also tried the Web Platform Installer and using the command line, all with the same end result.

Comment: Can you confirm if the .Net Components have installed successfully?

Comment: They are installed ok as part of the install, but they too roll back with a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

While building a Windows 7 64-bit machine I encountered problems when I was trying to install IIS (from Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off).

The installation progress bar would almost reach the end pretty quickly but then sit there. Eventually Windows would hang with neither pointer or keyboard responding.

However, I decided to try out IIS installation from a Safe Mode boot and it worked first time. I don't know what the cause of the problem was, but, I'm up and running now so it is worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked for me. Reason given was that my client uses Symantec Workstation Virtualization software which interferes in the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Check the IIS installation log:

1. Open notepad as a system administrator
2. Click File -> Open and enter "%windir%\iis7.log"

That should show the progress and highlight any errors.